# Determining if a collection is ready and a document exists

Tags: meteor

Say I have a page which shows a record from a mongodb collection:

```
var item = Items.findOne({name: documentName});
Session.set('item', item);
```

This will update my template with the item when the collection is ready and when a result is found. Now I can make an assumption that while Session.get('item') is undefined that the data is being loaded and show the user a loading graphic or message. However if the document does not exist I dont want to show the user a loading message indefinitely, I'd rather show a 'not found' message. How can I determine and inform the user if the record doesnt exist at all?

I thought about:

1. setting the item session variable to something like 'loaded'
2. showing the loading message while it has that value
3. and then showing the item or a 'not found' message when the collection returns undefined or the document.

That doesnt work however because the query will immediately return undefined until the collection is available and then if the query completes and the value is still undefined there has been no change and the session variable wont update.

I feel like I'm missing some trick thats right in front of my face! Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091885/how-to-run-method-on-client-when-subscribe-is-complete/16094801#16094801

Comment: Thanks Xyand, that does the trick nicely!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work for displaying "LOADING" message.

For displaying "NOT FOUND" message, check for type of the result of query in the template helper. The result will be `undefined` when there are no records in the collection.

```
    Template.items.item = function(){
      var item = Items.findOne({name: documentName});
      if(typeof item == 'undefined'){
         return null;
      }
      else{
         return item;
      }
    }
```

And in the html code, use `{{#if}}..{{else}}..{{/if}}` block helpers as:

```
    {{#if item}}
       <!-- Display your template data here -->
    {{else}}
       <!-- The template helper returned null, so display message here -->
       <span>NOT FOUND</span>           
    {{/if}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your suggestion this would still cause the user to see a loading message indefinitely as the loaded session var is set when the collection return undefined... which it always will if the document doesnt exist